# Disable native shake-effect on react-native (expo)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, shake, expo

I have project with react-native (ios) with `react-native-shake-event` lib and I works with Expo.
Unfortunately, when I try to shake device I see dev-menu, because it shows on "shake event" too, so I can't test my own shake effect.

Does somebody know, how I can avoid this? (if can) 
I need to check my custom effect on shake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try your app in prod mode. See [the expo doc here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/development-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable showing the developer menu on shake in the Expo app settings.

Comment: As of May 26th 2023, you can't. There is no option for this in the Expo Go app settings.

Comment: There definitely is in the iOS Expo app. I'm not able to confirm on Android.